# Change Phonegap layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is there any way to change the main.xml layout of Phonegap in Android? I have an iPhone Application with an UITabBar and a UIWebView, i use the tabs to change the URL of the UIWebView.

However whatever i change in the main.xml nothing changes, probably because i had to change the class to DroidGap.

Is there any way to change it? Or maybe an Plugin of some sort?

Regards,

Erik Terwan

Comment: Why do u want to change main.xml?... Once when we configure this phonegap for android then we dont use this main.xml.. We write javascript code to obtain various Functionality.. What is it u actually want?

Comment: I want to still be able to edit the native layout when using PhoneGap. But i already found a solution, using the slightly buggy iScroll.

Answer (score 1):

Just by adding in tabs in the main.xml file won't get you to your desired functionality. You also have to set up your tabs by binding intents to them in your onCreate within your activity class.

iOS has the interface builder where you can pretty much drag lines to make the connections (IBAction, etc) but you have to do all that from code on the Android side. Then from within those intents (or you can even overload the your tab hosts ontabchanged function) you can alter your WebView's location with `loadUrl();`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using JQuery Mobile for UI development. Check out http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36868306/UI%20Development%20using%20jQueryMobile